# Google analytics does not show Event Value in real-time?

Tags: google-analytics, real-time

I sent eventValue to Google Analytics. Is there anyway to show that in Realtime ??

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject])
```

ref : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 5):

No. You have obviously already checked the interface, and for the API the [list of available dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) does not include the event value.

Comment: When can I see the event value in the dashboard?
I mean if it is not available in Real Time then where to find it?

Comment: Behaviour->Events->Top Events, the fourth column. Note that event value is a metric, it only works when you have passed in an integer, and metric are added up (i.e. you cannot do a report that show all events where the value equals a specific number). If you pass in anything else than an integer your event might not be tracked at all.

Comment: Does this take time to update? in Real-time it showed on the spot (I get it). Now its been 1 hour since that data, still it isn't showing anything.

Comment: Data latency in Google Analytics is 24 hours for free accounts and 4 hours for GA360 accounts (usually the update happens much quicker, but that's what Google promises as per documentation).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I think I will add the comment here if I need you 2moro.